# Why is batch inserting data with Hibernate on Oracle much slower with a larger transaction?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

My current project includes an archiving function where data from an in-memory database is transferred to a relational database.

I stream over the results from the in-memory database, create hibernate entities and persist the data to the database in batches of 5000. These entities have a couple of relations so per entity I write to different tables.

As a reference you can assume that 1 million insert queries are executed in the entire archiving process.

This process was really slow in the beginning so I looked online and implemented some common suggestions for writing in batches with Hibernate:

- I set hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to a good size and hibernate.order_inserts to true.
- To prevent memory issues, every now and then I flush and clear the hibernate session.

Here is a small example of the batching:

```
RedisServiceImpl.Cursor<Contract> ctrCursor = contractAccessService.getCursor("*", taskId);

Iterators.partition(ctrCursor, BATCH_SIZE).forEachRemaining(chunk -> {

    portfolioChunkSaver.saveContractChunk(chunk, taskId);

    em.flush();
    em.clear();
});

ctrCursor.close();
```

This process works but it is incredibly slow. Inserting the 1 million records in Oracle took about 2 hours to finish, which is ~2.5 queries per second.

Currently this entire archiving function is wrapped in 1 transaction, which doesn't feel right at all. The big benefit is that you can be sure if the archive was successfully completed or not without having to provide some additional checking system for that. (Everything is either in the DB or it isn't)

As a speedup experiment I modified the code to create a database transaction per chunk of entities (5000) instead of wrapping everything in 1 big transaction.

That change had a huge impact, the speed now is about 10-15x as fast as before.

When profiling I saw this behavior before the change:

```
Before: 
Java - very low CPU
Oracle - very high CPU, low disk write activity

After:
Java - high CPU
Oracle - Low CPU, very high disk write activity
```

The second behavior makes a lot of sense, java is sending over as much queries as possible and the database server is constrained by the writing to disk speed on my local system.

Here comes my question: why is the impact so huge? What is Oracle doing differently when I send over everything in a bigger transaction?

As a side-note: I never had this issue with MySQL so Oracle (or the oracle JDBC driver) must be doing something in a different way.

I can imagine that guaranteeing ACID compliance causes the overhead, but I wouldn't expect this huge speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have enough UNDO space (also known as UNDO segments) as a large transaction will consume a lot of it.

> When a ROLLBACK statement is issued, undo records are used to undo
>   changes that were made to the database by the uncommitted transaction.

It's always preferable to only commit when you're done for data integrity and a properly tuned Oracle database can support large transactions without any performance issue.